# How can I read a paragraph as a single string in C?

Tags: c, string

I'm writing a C program that should read in an essay from a user.  The essay is divided into multiple paragraphs.
I don't know how many lines or characters the essay will be, but I do know that it ends with a hash symbol (`#`).  I want to use only as much memory as is necessary to hold the essay.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


main(){

    int size;
    char *essay;

    printf("\n how many characters?\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    essay =(char *) malloc(size+1);
    printf("Type the string\n");
    scanf("%s",essay);

    printf("%s",essay );

}
```

As I said before, I don't know (and don't want to ask) about the number of characters beforehand.  How do I dynamically allocate memory to save space? (What is dynamic memory allocation?) Is there another way to save memory that doesn't rely on dynamic allocation?

Additionally, my code only reads one line at a time right now.  How can I read multiple lines and store them as a single string?

this is another code

```
 #include<stdio.h>

main() {
   char essay[100];

   printf("Type the essay:\n");
   scanf("%[^#]s",  essay);

   printf("the essay : \n%s", essay);


}
```

it is working but it is wrong specify the number of characters

Comment: *"(What is dynamic memory allocation?)"* — and that's how your question became too broad.

Comment: Are you sure you need to get the number of chars from the user ? It seems a bit difficult for the user to answer that. If you could read from a file it would be simpler. One solution could be to allocate 500 chars and when this amount is used you reallocate more memory or your write that and reuse same memory. It's up to you.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: That was actually my edit on the original question...it was my attempt to sum up the original message of the question, which included "how can I use 'dynamic allocation of memory'".  I assumed at that point the OP wasn't sure what it was in the first place.